# I'm suffering from "Tab-itus", Opening the same site in multiple tabs

Tags: browser-addons, browser-tabs

I frequently find myself losing track of which tab has a particular site or dashboard that I need for my daily work. I routinely have upwards of 20-30 tabs open at one time.

Does anyone know of a browser add on or tab manager that will help?

Ideally, if I open a new tab and start typing a URL that's already open in an existing tab, I'd like the tab to take focus, or change color to alert me where it is.

Comment: Firefox, Chrome, IE??

Comment: Opera, Safari, Netscape Navigator, wget??

Comment: Opera allows you to store your tabs in groups and I think there was a chrome addon that does something very similar to what you want, but I can't remember the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox 4 and above will let you know if a tab is already open in the same process if you start typing in the Awesomebar and will let you switch to it.

Comment: You can also try new experiment on chrome